# How to distinct with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on T-SQL. I got a table like this.

```
x   y   z   t
1   avc 45353   11.02.2019
2   avc 24324   29.05.2019
3   frg 54647   30.06.2019
3   dsc 35678   29.05.2019
4   dec 21445   13.04.2019
4   dec 21445   19.04.2019
5   exc 24324   29.05.2019
6   xyz 37777   29.05.2019
7   xyz 37777   29.05.2019
```

I want to write a script that will give me only different "z" values for each "y" values.
I can't group by "y" only I got "Column 'x' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." error.

How can I fix this?

My outcome should be like this:

```
x   y   z   t
1   avc 45353   11.02.2019
2   avc 24324   29.05.2019
3   frg 54647   30.06.2019
3   dsc 35678   29.05.2019
4   dec 21445   13.04.2019
5   exc 24324   29.05.2019
6   xyz 37777   29.05.2019
```

Comment: show your expected output in table format

Comment: I edited my question for my expected outcome, the z column has distinct values for each "y" values.

Comment: Can you share which statement you already tried and gave that error? Also, it is easier for us when you format your input and expected output as text, not as images, then we can use it ourselves to reproduce things :-)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: I created table in Excel, when I copy, it is stored as image. I edited I copied as plain text but data looks complicated.

Comment: If you select the pasted text and press ctrl+K it will be formatted nicely

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by y, z order by t) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: I applied this but it still gives me same "y" values like "xyz" twice.

Comment: In your script I excluded x,  I think it worked out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this. And in the order, you can specify which records should be taken in the first place. In the example below, records with a lower value in the column t will be taken in the first place.

```
if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#temp') is not null
    drop table #temp
create table #temp
(
    x int
    ,y varchar(10)
    ,z int 
    ,t varchar(20)
)
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
(1,   'avc', 45353,   '11.02.2019' )
,(2,   'avc', 24324,   '29.05.2019' )
,(3,   'frg', 54647,   '30.06.2019' )
,(3,   'dsc', 35678,   '29.05.2019' )
,(4,   'dec', 21445,   '13.04.2019' )
,(4,   'dec', 21445,   '19.04.2019' )
,(5,   'exc', 24324,   '29.05.2019' )
,(6,   'xyz', 37777,   '29.05.2019' )
,(7,   'xyz', 37777,   '29.05.2019' )

SELECT
     x
    ,y
    ,z
    ,t
from (
select 
     x
    ,y
    ,z
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by y,z order by t asc) as [rank]
    ,t 
from #temp
) drv_tbl
where drv_tbl.rank = 1
order by 1
```

Comment: This is the identical answer with https://stackoverflow.com/a/59944283/10532500

Answer (score 0):

you can use,

If you wanted the first date use `min(t)` or use `max(t)` in case you want the last date

```
select x,y,z,min(t) as t from test group by x,y,z
```

I think, [Fahmi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944118/how-to-distinct-with-condition/59944283#59944283) better

Comment: In my table, time is irrelevant and I have examples like time is equal for all x, y, z values.

Comment: In link you should give the answer reference link it will be more suitable rather than giving profile reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/59944283/10532500

Answer (score -1):

Edit: reformatted my answer.
Is it what are you looking for ?:

```
SELECT x,y,z,t FROM table_name GROUP BY y,z,x,t
```

Error says that you have to add each of the columns to the group by

Comment: @sebnears Does your table contains identity column i.e., any primary key column.

Comment: Well didn't see edited question most primitive workaround would be to add "HAVING x=(SELECT min(tab2.x) FROM table_name tab2 WHERE tab1.y = tab2.y AND tab1.z = tab2.z AND tab1.t = tab1.t)" to my answer that's not best solution

Comment: @SurajKumar no there isn't any primary column

Answer (score -1):

just add having COUNT(y) >1 to your condition